# Converting PNG file into SVG format in Corel Draw x7

Tags: svg, coreldraw

What is the correct sequence of actions to convert PNG file in SVG format in Corel Draw? I import the image into a new file, then export it (selected only) into SVG format. But as a result I get very low-quality image, much worse than PNG.

Answer (score 1):

The lower quality is due to the fact that your image has been embedded in the SVG, and the image is no a vector.

Steps:

1. Import PNG Image
2. **Trace Bitmap *(From Bitmap Menu)***
3. Export to SVG

That's simple.

Answer (score 0):

1. select **Import** in file (ctrl+I)

[image]

2.select **png** and select **Export** in File (ctrl+E)

[image]

[image]

3.select **SVG** in **save as type** DropDown

[image]

4.Select the options as shown below

[image]